# What's wrong with this boolean iteration?

Tags: c#, foreach, boolean

While doing this bool iteration, I was tempted to use the non existing operator `||=`, and figured there must be a simpler or better design that would replace its valid use (rather than think it's just "missing"):

```
bool validExtension = false;

foreach (string extension in Plugin.Extensions)
{
    validExtension = validExtension || Path.GetExtension(file).Equals(extension.TrimStart('*'), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    if (validExtension)
    {
        break;
    }
}

importButton.Enabled = File.Exists(importTextBox.Text) && validExtension;
```

Comment: what is the typeof Plugin.Extensions?

Comment: @yetanothercoder: Does not really matter as long as you know it iterates strings.

Comment: You probably want to reverse the tests in the last line, no point in doing an expensive `File.Exists` test if `validExtension` is false.

Comment: @lazlo: for sake of curiosity, can i know? :)

Comment: @yetanothercoder `static readonly string[]`, as boring as can be.

Comment: @lazlo: there is another method for string[] i have posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That loop has an invariant: on entry to the body, `validExtension = false`.

So the body can be simplified to:

```
if (validExtension = Path.GetExtension(file).Equals(extension.TrimStart('*'), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    break;
```

If there wasn't such an invariant, you could use the compound assignment operator `|=` if you always wanted to evaluate the right-hand side, or `if (!lhs) lhs = rhs;` if you wanted short-circuiting.

Comment: == or =? also dont you wanna set validextension = true?

Comment: @yetanothercoder: `=`, single equals, which is assignment.  `validExtension` is being set.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. But what if I didn't have that invariant?

Comment: @Ben Voigt The assignment operation will almost always return true, unless the assignment fails (in which case you're app has bigger problems).  This will always break on the first pass.

Comment: @Lazlo: Read the last sentence, which starts out "If there wasn't an invariant"...

Comment: @nybbler: Who says an assignment operator evaluates to true whenever the assignment succeeds?  Cite some documentation or show sample code.  Because [my sample code works](http://ideone.com/nTe6o).

Comment: @Ben Vogit: +1 So silly of me. I debugged  and am convinced. thanks for this, as i didnt known this was possible at c#. thanks

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Luckily, C# has a bug.  You get the warning "Assignment in conditional expression is always constant; did you mean to use == instead of = ?" when checking for assignment to a boolean in a comparison statement. All other assignments in comparisons generate a compiler error for C#. This is non-standard, however, which makes me tend to avoid it due to its lack of clarity.

Comment: @nybbler: You must be talking about some other code, there's no constant here.  And `validExtension` has to be assigned because it's used outside the loop.  And it's perfectly standard, no bug at all, and perfectly consistent with C and C++.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: You commented as I was editing...and good catch. I did not notice that on the first pass.  If you read the warning text, it is not in line with what Microsoft intended.  It is a handy shorthand however, I will admit.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (string extension in Plugin.Extensions)
{
     if (Path.GetExtension(file).Equals(extension.TrimStart('*'), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
     {
          validExtension = true;
          break;
     }
}
```

This works because you are breaking the first time you find a valid extension, so `validExtension` is always false on the first line of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

can't you just say `validExtension = Path.Get....` since at the start of the expression validExtension will always be false.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no `||=` operator in C#, there is the `|=` operator that may be what you're looking for. 
[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx)

Comment: But that doesn't short-circuit, which in some contexts might be important (it isn't here, because the prior value is always `false` so short-circuiting would never occur).

Answer (score 0):

If its a string[], the whole code can be changed like this

```
Func<string[], string, bool> validExtension = (arr, s) => arr.Contains(s);
importButton.Enabled = validExtension(Plugin.Extensions, Path.GetExtension(file)) && File.Exists(importTextBox.Text);
```

For checking a value inside an Array you could always use [`Array.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384015%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) extension method.
P.S: I have reversed the tests as Ben Voigt rightfully said